# Is there a simpler way to solve the differential equation $y''+2xy'+(x^2-1)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A student asked me to solve this differential equation
$$y''+2 x y'+(x^2-1)y=0$$
Is there a method simpler than power series?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I think this is a "2nd-order exact" equation.  I don't recall the technique, but probably the LHS can be written as the 2nd-derivative of some product.

Comment: @B.Goddard which product ?

Comment: It should be something like the 2nd derivative of $y(x^2-1).$  But you'd do better googling than relying on my memory.  I think I solved one of these only once in my life.

Comment: For equation $y'' + py' +qy = 0$, try $y = v\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\int p\text dx)$ substitution to eliminate middle term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to express this as the second derivative of some function of $x$ and $y$. Via the ansatz introduction of $e^{-x^2/2}$ (motivated because the coefficients of the derivatives of $y$ are decreasing linearly in degree, and then just guessing), we note that $$\frac{d^2}{d x^2} e^{-x^2/2} y = e^{-x^2/2} \left(y'' - 2x y' + (x^2 - 1) y\right).$$ If we solve this differential equation, then a substitution of $-x$ at the end will yield solutions to our actual equation. Clearly the solutions to this differential equation are $$y = c_1 e^{x^2/2} x  + c_2 e^{x^2/2}.$$ By substituting $-x$ into this equation, we obtain the solutions to the original differential equation, i.e. $$y = c_1 e^{x^2/2} (-x) + c_2 e^{x^2/2}.$$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I've realised that my hint was perhaps rather insufficient, so I've edited the answer with a complete solution.